# Getting One-Time Read Data From Nested Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to make an app that need to read data just for one time from a nested Firestore Database.

Here's my currently working code

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('users');
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    FutureBuilder getTheData = FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError || (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists)) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          String _condition = data['condition'];
          String _descCondition = data['descCondition'];
          int _percentageValue = data['percentageValue'];

          return defaultDraw(
            condition: _condition,
            descCondition: _descCondition,
            percentageValue: _percentageValue,
          );
        }

        return defaultDraw(
          condition: "Loading",
          descCondition: "",
          percentageValue: 0,
        );
      },
    );
```

and it's able to read this data (condition, descCondition, and percentageValue) :
[image]

but when I'm trying to read this data :
[image]
Which is another collection inside of the previous document (a collection named 'adviceData' with random document ID that I'm trying to read), I'm getting an error like this :

[image]

Here's my code :

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('users');
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    FutureBuilder _getParameterData = FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users
          .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('adviceData')
          .doc()
          .get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError || (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists)) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

          String _advicePhLow = data['advicePhLow'];
          String _advicePhHigh = data['advicePhHigh'];
          String _adviceTempLow = data['adviceTempLow'];
          String _adviceTempHigh = data['adviceTempHigh'];
          String _adviceHeightLow = data['adviceHeightLow'];
          String _adviceHeightHigh = data['adviceHeightHigh'];

          return drawParameter(
            advicePhLow: _advicePhLow,
            adviceTempLow: _adviceTempLow,
            adviceHeightLow: _adviceHeightLow,
          );
        }

        return drawParameter();
      },
    );
```

and my question is :

1. Where did I make mistakes?
2. Is there any better method to get a data from firestore?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all `documents` from the subcollection `adviceData` you would need to get a `QuerySnapshot` like here:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      future: users
          .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('adviceData')
          .get(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['full_name']),
              subtitle: Text(data['company']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

If you want to get a single `document` from that subcollection you would need to define the `id` of that specific document:

```
 FutureBuilder _getParameterData = FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users
          .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection('adviceData')
          .doc('documentID') // here
          .get(),
      builder:
```

You can find more about both methods [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#read-data).

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm. But some more question though, if I used QuerySnapshot, how to read the data? Should I map it as a list or something? and for the specific document ID, should I always get the ID manually or can I get it automatically (without getting it hardcoded in the app)?

Comment: I have expanded the answer code to demonstrate how to handle the `QuerySnapshot`. When reading a single `document` you can either get it manually or with a `QuerySnapshot`. But with the `QuerySnapshot` you already have the data with the `id`.

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much sir. Your answer really helped me on this project a lot! I will definitely read your reference. Again, thank you very much! :D